# Can I flash a PCI-E device's Firmware in a VM if the VM has exclusive IOMMU access?

Tags: vmware-esx, dell-perc, firmware, pci-express, passthrough

I have a PCI-E Dell Perc 6/i  RAID card  that I'd like to flash with the latest firmware.  Apparently I need either a Redhat / Centos  OS or Windows in order to flash the firmware,  but I have a VMWare 5.0.1 ESX  hypervisor installed on the box and a CentOS guest OS.  My motherboard support IOMMU and I have successfully used VMWare's PCI Passthrough feature to give VMs exclusive access to a PCI-E device.   Is it safe to flash the firmware of a PCI-E device if that device is passed through to a single VM using the passthrough feature of VMware?  Or should I boot one of the supported OSes directly on the bare metal?

Comment: If that RAID card is in use by the host you could have some... Undesirable effects on the host when you disconnect it (speaking from experience here, I still have an orphaned VM that I can't shut down because of unexpected removal of storage)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.  You can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Doable... I needed to do it with an [LSI 9211-8i controller enabled through passthrough](https://serverfault.com/a/398579/13325).