# ESXi free scripting

Tags: vmware-esxi, scripting, command-line-interface

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to script commands on the esxi system to run commands on the esxi system after the first auto start vm at a specific time after it is powered on before the next vm is powered on?  esxcfg-nas -r needs to be run as well as some other housekeeping tasks.

Comment: ESXi is not a general-purpose operating system. What type of housekeeping tasks are you planning?

Comment: i Need the first vm to come up so that the others can start properly, after it comes up i need to run esx-nas -r  and then start/restart any vm using those resources.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this the wrong way.

If you're trying to set VM order for an [all-in-one ESXi/NAS](https://serverfault.com/questions/398515/hosting-a-zfs-server-as-a-virtual-guest/398579#398579) solution, just set your order in `Configuration -> Virtual Machine Start and Shutdown`. Make your NFS server #1. There's no need to run `esxcfg-nas -r`. If it's exporting a datastore, ESXi will make it available once the VM comes up.

[image]

Comment: I wish that were the case.  my nas is the first in line and the datastore never becomes active unless I Manually activate it.  startup delay on the nas is 30  the rest are in the 100's