# Can Docker Corrupt a Software RAID Setup?

Tags: raid, docker, raid1, lxc, raid10

I [read](https://serverfault.com/questions/519688/software-raid-underneath-esxi-datastore) that software RAID should not be implemented on a machine that also has ESXi virtual machines running. Does this mean that I would want to avoid LVM and or LXC/Docker containers as well on this server?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you read it? The reasoning should be there. More context would be super useful.

Comment: I read it here. I have updated the question with the link.
http://serverfault.com/questions/519688/software-raid-underneath-esxi-datastore

Comment: The question you are referencing was asking about using software RAID within a VM. Software RAID within a VM is not recommended, it belongs at a lower layer than that. Why you couldn't use software RAID at the hypervisor level is however not explained by any of the answers to that other question. I don't know any specific reason why that shouldn't work, though the answers you point to imply it doesn't. Based on that I am voting to reopen this question, because it seems clear to me what information you are missing.

Comment: docker broke my weekly checking of RAID - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178811/unable-to-check-a-mdadm-raid1-array-says-the-file-systems-read-only

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LXC/Docker by design doesn't have anything to do with RAID (any RAID) at all.
Docker/LXC containers are run on the same kernel as the host.
As such I don't think there are any docker related problems.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, RAID10 is the *preferred* RAID level for high-performance virtual machines. While it has its shortcoming, I can not see why it should not be used with ESXi or Docker.

Back to original question: docker mainly is a user-space affaire. So it can not corrupt a software or hardware RAID device.

As a side note, I strongly advise you *against* cheap RAID cards. If you really want to do hardware RAID, buy a card with a DRAM cache and a BBU/NV module.

Answer (score 1):

All software running on the machine operates as if the RAID is 1 device. This is why usually the device is `/dev/sdc`  instead of seeing `/dev/sda`  and then also `/dev/sdb`.

If you're using a software RAID vs a RAID card then it's plausible that something on the OS could cause the OS injected RAID to not behave properly.  I know people use them all the time but **I highly suggest using a RAID card** — even a cheap one if you have too, it's worth of loading this functionality to its own hardware