# Is it a good a idea to create a fake raid 1 for guest on ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, ubuntu-14.04, software-raid

I have an old server with software raid and I would like to install ESXi with 2 hard disks.

I have read that I can install a guest (i.e. Ubuntu Server) and add two hard disks in different datastores to create a fake raid 1 setup.

Is it a good idea in terms of redundancy? I know that ESXi will no have nothing to do with the raid configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Fake RAID is never a good idea. There are many, far better ways to sabotage a system.

Comment: You might be better off switching to another hypervisor that will do a software RAID, or support your fakeraid controller, if you really want to use this hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a good idea.

If you want to run VMware and have RAID protection, you need a supported hardware RAID solution.

Please see: [Software RAID underneath ESXi datastore](https://serverfault.com/questions/519688/software-raid-underneath-esxi-datastore)