# What cable do I require for SFF-8087 to SAS

Tags: hp, hardware-raid, sas, hp-smart-array, cable

I have a HP P410 and two 2.5" SAS Drives, i want to connect both those SAS drives to one port. I know the cable for the P410 is a SFF-8087 and ive seen plenty of adapters searching, but alot of them go from SFF-8087 to 4 x SATA. I know I cant connect those sata cables to SAS, so not sure what i need here.

Can someone point me to a website or cable that has what i need?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you doing this in a non-HP server without a backplane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector you're looking for, to plug into your SAS drives, is SFF-8482.

So you will shop for a cable with SFF-8087 on one end and (multiple) SFF-8482 on the other.

Comment: Afaik [these cables are directional](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1614519) so one has to make sure that both the connectors and the direction are right - in this case the SFF-8087 has to be on the host side.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in a *non-HP server* without a backplane? HISS!!

[This is not an ideal arrangement if so, and you'll need to be careful](https://serverfault.com/questions/526187/drives-randomly-dropping-from-raid-array).

The only cables I'd use for this are HP's branded SAS breakout cable or the [LSI SAS breakout cable](https://store.lsi.com/store.cfm/Internal_Multi-Lane_Cables/All_Cables/CBL-SAS8087OCF-06M/). How do you plan to power the drives? The LSI cable (*pictured below*) has power injector ports for regular 4-pin Molex power cables.

[image]