# SAS disk and intel motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, sas, intel, hardware

What kind of Cable shall I use to connect [ [http://www.amazon.com/SAS-Enterprise-Hard-Drive-WD1001FYYG/dp/B0090UELTW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0090UELTW) ] and server board: http://ark.intel.com/products/56334/intel-server-board-s2600cp4

in the board specification i have : Integrated SAS Ports 8, so what are they ? how to use them ?

Comment: May be you need some kind of activation key ? I think it is not very common to use this mother board with SAS drives,

Answer (score 1):

You need a SAS breakout cable, but the specifics depend on whether you will be using a backplane for the disks or not.

If you're using a single bare drive with no backplane, you'll want an SFF-8087 connector on the motherboard side and 4 x SFF-8482 for the disks.

[image]

Please see:
 [How exactly does a SAS SFF-8087 breakout cable work? + RAID/connection questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/510442/how-exactly-does-a-sas-sff-8087-breakout-cable-work-raid-connection-questions/510445#510445)

and

[What cable do I require for SFF-8087 to SAS](https://serverfault.com/questions/526475/what-cable-do-i-require-for-sff-8087-to-sas/526518#526518)

Comment: Are you sure that board has a SFF-8087 connection? I don't see it in the pictures...

Comment: Most server boards have SFF-8087... But if this thing has SATA headers on the motherboard, then a different cable is needed.

Comment: -1 Sorry, had to dig into the manual (I hate Intel mobos....), those blue SATA connections on the board are actually SAS.

Comment: So I got a SAS board + SAS hd - what kind of cable is going to work here?

Answer (score 1):

You need a SATA to SFF-8482 cable. They're relatively easy to find on eBay.

That is a dual-port drive, so you can use the cables with 2 SATA connections (to add redundancy). Make sure you plug the SATA connector into the *blue* connections on the motherboard (the blue connections are SAS, the black and white connections are SATA only).

**Jab at Intel:** The cable in Ed's answer is the industry standard that almost everyone uses. These goofy cables with non-standard connections are just one of the reasons I steer clear of Intel motherboards. Also, the documentation is horrid, took me minutes to figure out how to plug a hard drive into that darn motherboard... seriously, minutes. It shouldn't take but seconds on their spec page.

Comment: I bought cable ( please see: http://imgur.com/1AtFt86 + http://imgur.com/fuHYuP1 ). Is that a cable you recommended ? Anyways I plug it into the blue connections on motherboard (SAS) and plug molex as well. I cannot see HD in bios

Comment: @kamjel That should be the correct cable. I have not read all the details on that motherboard. There's likely a setting in the BIOS, jumper, or similar configuration item that needs to be set before the drive will be recognized.

Comment: any ideas what configuration item exactly ?

Comment: When connecting it via SFF-8482 cable it does not seem to work. I cannot even hear or feel HD working

Comment: I really avoid Intel's crap like the plague, so no idea what configuration without diving into their hideous manual again. SCSI/SAS disks do not spin-up until the host controller tells them to. Only ATA disks spin-up without being told to.