# Why am I getting only 1gbps between Solaris and VMware?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, solaris

I have a VMWare ESXi 5.1.0 (build 1065491) host running a [Solaris (OpenIndiana)](http://openindiana.org/) VM as a guest. I have created a private vSwitch for NFS traffic between ESXi and Solaris. The Solaris VM has the VMware tools installed and has a VMXnet3 adaptor (`vmxnet3s0`) on the private vSwitch.

Reading from a file directly on the Solaris VM using `dd` I get speeds of up to 4.5 GB/sec (44.8 gigabit/sec) when reading a file (if it has been cached by my ARC/L2ARC)

Reading the same file over NFS from VMware, I can only get a maximum of 0.163 GB/sec (1.131 gigabit/sec)

Why is there such a difference? I expect some overhead due to TCP and NFS, as well as virtual networking, but that difference isn't what I'd call *overhead*, it looks like something's wrong.

The CPU on the Solaris VM is never more than 20% used. Load averages are low. Plenty of free RAM on the host (it's not swapping) and CPU utilization on the host is well below 50% (typically around 33%). On the guest VM, `dladm show-linkprop vmxnet3s0` shows that the speed is 10000 (10 Gbit/sec) and the MTU is 9000 (Jumbo Frames enabled)

As a test I tried using a "standard" E1000 vmnic (`e1000g0`) and I was able to enable jumbo frames (9000 MTU) however reading the same file over NFS from VMware, I can only get a maximum of 0.124 GB/sec (0.992 gigabit/sec) which makes sense as the link speed on the E1000 is only 1000 megabit.

Why am I only seeing only about 1 gigabit/second transfer speeds between VMware ESXi 5.1 and my OpenIndiana Solaris VM?

---

**UPDATE:** After applying the performance tuning recommended by VFrontDe in his answer, I'm now getting an impressive 8-9 Gbit/sec between Solaris and a Linux VM with a `vmxnet3` adapter. I'm getting ~6 Gbps reading a cached file via NFS under Linux:

```
root@iperf:/mnt/public/ISO# dd if=Test.cdr of=/dev/null bs=1024k
5884+1 records in
5884+1 records out
6170824704 bytes (6.2 GB) copied, 8.44985 s, 730 MB/s
```

However Reading that same file on the VMware ESXi host, I get an abysmal 1.91 Gbps:

```
/vmfs/volumes/3d77318f-82c7901a/ISO # time dd if=Windows\ 7\ Home\ Premium.cdr of=/dev/null bs=1024k
5884+1 records in
5884+1 records out
real    0m 27.85s
user    0m 17.32s
sys     0m 0.00s
```

[6.2 GB in 27.85 seconds works out to be 1.91 gbps](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%286.2+GiB+%2F+27.85seconds%29+in+gbps).

**What is causing Vmware ESXi's `vmknic` to perform so poorly when `vmxnet3` to `vmxnet3` is so much better?**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are some issues and bugs with the vmxnet3 adapter for Solaris. Please have a look at this very detailed post: http://blog.cyberexplorer.me/2013/03/improving-vm-to-vm-network-throughput.html The author was able to get much better throughput after some tweaking, but it's too much to repeat all steps here.

Comment: Thanks. This was *almost* it, but I need some tuning on the VMware side. I'm not getting ~8-9 gbps between VMs on the host, but still only ~1-3 gbps between the VM and the host itself...